# What is the correct syntax to write an email that will make an ical event?

Tags: email, calendar, icalendar

Hi I'm looking for the right syntax to have a plain text email to trigger a complete ical event:

Venerdì 13 Novembre 14:30 Academy Piazzale Susa 2

does give me the time and date

Academy Venerdì 13 Novembre 14:30 Piazzale Susa 2 20121 Milano

gives me also the place

how do I insert the title "Academy"?

what other possibilities are there to add events details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really broad. The starting point is https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6047

The "title" of an event corresponds to the SUMMARY property.
The "place" corresponds to the LOCATION property.